# Calendar for daily planning with multi-select and bulk move

Tags: windows, web-apps, time-management, calendar, planning

I am looking for a calendar app that does the following:

1. Allow me create events anywhere between 5 min and 2 hours easily to plan out my daily work.
2. Allow me to multi-select a number of consecutive events easily, e.g. by shift-clicking the first and the last or by using box selection.
3. Allow me to move all those events together, e.g. shift them by an hour to make room for something that comes up in between.

I have tried Thunderbird, Google Calendar, Apple iCloud Calendar and the Windows 10 Calendar app, none of which support the moving of multiple events.

Windows or a web-app. Free is preferrable, but paid works as well. Thanks!